# Before customer login check condition in magento 2.4

Tags: customer, login, magento2.4

I want to if customer login and customer cart is not empty so customer redirect checkout page other wise customer login and customer cart is empty customer redirect my account page.

Please help me,

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Hi! II'm not sure what you want to achieve. The redirect must occur on login action, right? So, when user logs in: If cart is empty -> redirect to account page; if cart is not empty -> redirect to checkout page. Is that right?

Comment: Yes right. when user logs in: If cart is empty -> redirect to account page; if cart is not empty -> redirect to checkout page

Comment: Thanks! I'll prepare the answer for you ;)

Comment: Thanks! @dudzio

Comment: @MohitPatel Please check the answer and update me.

Comment: @MohitPatel I've placed my answer too, sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check quote items count after `LoginPost` action.

The `di.xml` (preferably `frontend/di.xml` since you only need to do the redirect on front) code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_redirect_after_login" type="Vendor\Magento\Plugin\RedirectAfterLogin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Check items count and handle redirects  in your plugin code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class RedirectAfterLogin
{

    protected \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Redirect after login in some conditions
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($this->getInCartItems()) {
            $result->setPath('checkout');
        } else {
            $result->setPath('customer/account');
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getInCartItems()
    {
        try {
            $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
            return $quote->getItemsCount();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please @dudzio help me on this question :-  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/340530/85907

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_loginpostplugin" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin\LoginPostPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class LoginPostPlugin
{

    protected $customerSession;
    protected $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $customerData = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerData);
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        if (count($items)) {
            $result->setPath('checkout');
            return $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the below code**

**1**.Create a **events.xml** file under "Namespace/Module/etc/frontend"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="custom_login_data" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CustomerData" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2**.Create a observer(**CustomerData.php**) under "Namespace/Module/Observer"

```
    <?php
        /**
         * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */
        namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;
        
        use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
        
        class CustomerData implements ObserverInterface
        {
            protected $_request;
            protected $groupRepository;You can also use the cart helper
            protected $cartHelper;
            private $responseFactory;
            private $url;
            
            public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,         \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
            {
                $this->_request = $request;
                $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
                $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
                $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
                $this->url = $url;
    
            }
        
            /**
             *
             * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
             * @return void
             */
            public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
            {
              if ($this->cartHelper->getItemsCount() > 0) {
               $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout');
               $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
              }
                return $this;
            }
      
           
            }
 }
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: i have already try this solution and again try you answer but not success.

Comment: Not success mean..any error or what?

Comment: No. Not showing any error