# created new custom export Entity Type in magento 2

Tags: magento2, export

I have created custom Entity Type in Magento 2 but not showing Entity Attributes list after selecting entity type.

[image]

Here is my code :-

```
<?php

namespace Test\Vendor\Model\Export;

/**
 * Class Constructs
 */
class Constructs extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * Permanent column names
     */
    const PATTERN_ID = 'pattern_id';
    const NAME = 'name';
    const SKU_PATTERN = 'sku_pattern';
    const SKU_LIST = 'sku_list';
    const STATUS = 'status';
    const STORE_ID = 'store_ids';

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        self::PATTERN_ID,
        self::NAME,
        self::SKU_PATTERN,
        self::SKU_LIST,
        self::STATUS,
        self::STORE_ID,
    ];

    public function export()
    {
        // TODO: Implement export() method.
    }

    public function exportItem($item)
    {
        // TODO: Implement exportItem() method.
    }

    public function getEntityTypeCode()
    {
        return  'constructs';
    }

    protected function _getHeaderColumns()
    {
        return $this->_permanentAttributes;
    }

    protected function _getEntityCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Implement _getEntityCollection() method.
    }
}
```

Also i have click on continue button showing this error :- **Please correct the data sent value.**

Comment: bro I have debugged core code actually Magento call Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\Export.php controller

Comment: and Magento store data into queue

Comment: Thanks. So its possible or not?

Comment: it's possible but we need to check how to set correct data. I tried a different way but no luck bro.

Comment: Thanks bro i will check

Comment: @MohitPatel, If you have solution please help me i am struck at it.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link. I hope this help for you

https://github.com/Smile-SA/magento2-module-custom-entity-import-export

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-export-a-custom-entity-from-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks but i want to entity export not import

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229902/i-want-to-add-my-custom-entity-for-export-magento-2

Comment: This link i have already follow and more explain what issue i have face in my question

Comment: my question i have totally explain.

Comment: set_time_limit and check

Comment: where put this code ? set_time_limit

Comment: in php.ini set memory_limit  and max_execution_time

Comment: how many records you export

Comment: only 10 records

Comment: i have set this set_time_limit but not working

Comment: I will check in my local.give me some time

Comment: yes Please and Thanks bro